How to make multiple groups of circle markers with different colors for each group?
I'm working on a project in which I'm trying to make an interactive map with leaflet. I can't figure out how to have multiple colors for my circle markers. I've got my "closed" group on the map but want to add two more categories of markers.
library(leaflet)

 leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = -155.66, lat = 19.89, zoom = 5) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = closed, color = "green")              


and this is the first category I actually managed to get in
lng -156.60, -156.87, -159.51, -159.53
lat 20.900, 21.140, 21.973, 22.120
and this is what I want to put in but in a different color
lng -155.6, -155.5, -156.9
lat 19.2, 19.2, 20.9
I've tried so many different ways of trying to combine my other data group, but nothing is running.

Please post sample data with dput. You need a grouping column to use for fillColor. See Change leaflet marker fill color by group.
